# Trying to run inference on VGG16 model: InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'N' of 1 must be at least minimum 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, transfer-learning

Trying to do binary image classification using VGG16 for transfer learning. This is my code for training:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

vgg16_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=True,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None,
    pooling=None,
    classes=1000,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
)

vgg16_model._layers.pop()  

model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
    model.add(layer)
    
   
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
   
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))    

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=.0001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        cwd + '/images/dd_notadd/train',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        cwd + '/images/dd_notadd/validation',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=10,
        epochs=20,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=10)
model.save("ddornot.h5")
```

Then this is my code for inference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Mar  7 11:12:16 2021

@author: lennartkonst
"""

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

cwd = os.getcwd()

vgg16_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=True,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None,
    pooling=None,
    classes=1000,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
)

vgg16_model._layers.pop()  

model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
    model.add(layer)


for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
   
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))       

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=.0001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 


model.load_weights("ddornot.h5")

testimagefilename = cwd + '/images/dd_notadd/testimage/testimage.jpeg'

img = cv2.imread(testimagefilename)
img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))

img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

print(img.shape)

img_class = model.predict(img, batch_size=1)
```

I get the following output on this inference script:

```
Model: "sequential_29"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_58 (Dense)             (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_59 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 8194      
=================================================================
Total params: 151,050,050
Trainable params: 16,789,506
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
_________________________________________________________________
(1, 224, 224, 3)
WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 7 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x7fb1487b9280> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/lennartkonst/Documents/Twitterbots/Pythonbots/DreamDestinationsBot/ML/ddornotinference.py", line 60, in <module>
    img_class = model.predict(img, batch_size=1)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 130, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1614, in predict
    all_outputs = nest.map_structure_up_to(batch_outputs, concat, outputs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 1135, in map_structure_up_to
    return map_structure_with_tuple_paths_up_to(

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 1234, in map_structure_with_tuple_paths_up_to
    results = [func(*args, **kwargs) for args in zip(flat_path_list,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 1234, in <listcomp>
    results = [func(*args, **kwargs) for args in zip(flat_path_list,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 1137, in <lambda>
    lambda _, *values: func(*values),  # Discards the path arg.

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2673, in concat
    return array_ops.concat(tensors, axis=axis)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1654, in concat
    return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1207, in concat_v2
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6843, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'N' of 1 must be at least minimum 2
    ; NodeDef: {{node ConcatV2}}; Op<name=ConcatV2; signature=values:N*T, axis:Tidx -> output:T; attr=N:int,min=2; attr=T:type; attr=Tidx:type,default=DT_INT32,allowed=[DT_INT32, DT_INT64]> [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
```

I don't fully understand what the problem is, I tried several different shapes but I figure the input shape should be just 1,224,224,3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see modified answer

Comment: I had a typo in my answer fixed it. What code creates the error? Did the model train?

Comment: Yes, the model trained with high accuracy. Both the VGG16 of my code as well as the VGG19 of your code. It's only when I try model.predict() I get the error of "
InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'N' of 1 must be at least minimum 2". I don't even know what it means. I also get that error with another script taken from this article https://towardsdatascience.com/10-minutes-to-building-a-binary-image-classifier-by-applying-transfer-learning-to-mobilenet-eab5a8719525. I really wonder I am the only one getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your generators specify class_mode as binary and you specify the loss as 'binary_crossentropy'. Therefore your dense layer at the top of the model should have a single neuron and the activation='sigmoid. Why do you bother to recreate the whole model for inference since you saved the entire model just load it with

```
model= keras.models.load_model("ddornot.h5")
```

You are reading in your test image using cv2. In that case if you have a color image it is in BGR format. Your model was trained on RGB images so you have to convert it with

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Note in your code for vgg16 you should have set

```
image_shape=(224,224,3)
```

Also you can try this for your model

```
base_model=tf.keras.applications.VGG19( include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling='max', weights='imagenet' )
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False 
x=base_model.output
x=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x) 
x= tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu)(x)
x= tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.2)(x)
predictions=tf.keras.layers.Deense(1, activation='sigmoid)(x) 
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=.0001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I still get the same error then. But thanks

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried what you said above with the VGG19 model, but I still keep on getting the error: InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'N' of 1 must be at least minimum 2. It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround the error. It's still not preferable off course so a good answer where I can just use model.predict() would be awesome.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
# from keras.models import Sequential
# from keras.layers import Activation, Dense
# from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
# import numpy as np
# import cv2

cwd = os.getcwd()

model= keras.models.load_model("ddornot.h5")       

model.summary()



validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

# Flow validation images in batches of 19 using valid_datagen generator
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        cwd + '/images/dd_notadd/testimage',  # This is the source directory for validation images
        classes = ['dd', 'notadd'],
        target_size=(224, 224),  # All images will be resized to 200x200
        batch_size=1,
        # Use binary labels
        class_mode='binary',
        shuffle=False)

STEP_SIZE_TEST=validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size
validation_generator.reset()
preds = model.predict(validation_generator,
                      verbose=1)

print(preds)



# testimagefilename = cwd + '/images/dd_notadd/testimage/testimage.jpeg'

# img = cv2.imread(testimagefilename)
# img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
# img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))

# img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

# print(img.shape)

# img_class = model.predict(img)
```